# Получение никнейма по ID пользователя Discord .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, discord

Есть бот, есть условная команда для бота `!nickname @user`, где @user - упоминание. После ввода, бот должен вывести никнейм пользователя на сервере. Не могу понять, как с помощью упоминания добыть ник.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552748/discord-net-discord-username-to-socketguilduser

Comment: У вас должны быть модули (отдельные классы, со своими методами под каждую команду). В методе просто пишете нужный тип, например `public async Task UserInfoAsync(SocketUser user){ ... }`, ну а действие `await ReplyAsync($"{user.Username}#{user.Discriminator}");` - отдаст ник с цифрами. Все, имея это, вы можете писать `команда @Упоминание`, можете написать `команда Ник#123`, можете написать `команда 1234567890123454565` (id человека), все это будет работать. Об этом кстати, написано в [документации](https://discordnet.dev/guides/text_commands/intro.html#command-context).